# Split a vector into two vectors randomly in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a vector that has 36 values and I'd like to split it into two vectors randomly. (The first vector has 25 values and the second has 11 values).

I have written this code (using MATLAB) but when I have repeated values in the original vector, I will not get 11 samples in the second vector as a result of this command

```
Second_vec = setdiff(orignal_Vec,First_vec);



clear;
load('U1_Acc_TimeD_FDay.mat' ); 

orignal_Vec=(Acc_TD_Feat_Vec (:,1)); 

Total_Samples = size(orignal_Vec,1);

Selected_Samples = 25; 

assert(Selected_Samples<=Total_Samples); 

rand_rows = randperm(Total_Samples, Selected_Samples);

First_vec = orignal_Vec(rand_rows,:);  % Select the random rows from the original Vector

Second_vec = setdiff(orignal_Vec,First_vec);
```

Comment: Use [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to generate indices and index into your data.

Comment: Dear Excaza,if you see my code above!  i already use it in order to create the first vector but i want the remaining values from the original vector to be in the second vector.

Comment: Why did you remove your code? You should roll back that edit and leave the code example there so people can see what you did and how it didn't work for you, for comparison with the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking I will confuse people, thank you so much for letting me know, I will attach it :).                                            by the way, I'm wondering if you could help me with the new question                                                                                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295449/calculating-euclidean-distance-in-matlab-template-matching                                                                                                as I already attached the complete code there in order to avoid the repetition. kind regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of generating 25 random integers using randperm, generate 36 random integers using the syntax `randperm(36)`. Then you can use the first 25 elements from this random integer vector to index into original vector to get your first vector and then use the rest for the second vector. Your modified code below.

```
clear;
load('U1_Acc_TimeD_FDay.mat' ); 

orignal_Vec=(Acc_TD_Feat_Vec (:,1)); 

Total_Samples = size(orignal_Vec,1);

Selected_Samples = 25; 

assert(Selected_Samples<=Total_Samples); 

rand_rows = randperm(Total_Samples);

First_vec = orignal_Vec(rand_rows(1:Selected_Samples));  % Select the random rows from the original Vector

Second_vec = orignal_Vec(rand_rows(Selected_Samples+1:end));
```

Comment: Dear Navan, thank you so much. i guess you misunderstand my question. I already have the vector ( Which is orignal_Vec) . So, i don't want to generate random integer values! because i already have my values stored in orignal_Vec. all I want to do to split the Orignial Vector into two vectors randomly. the first vector has 25 values and the second one has 11 values ! thank you again for your answer

Comment: @Neamah That is what his code is doing.  Try running it.  It loads the data like yours does, then it uses `randperm` to effectively shuffle the values in your `original_Vec` array.